# My app gets stuck on a white screen that says copyright stuff when i run it in a ios simulator

Tags: ios, swift, screen

this is my first time doing ios project and everytime i try to run this app , its stuck on the white screen . Any ideas or solutions to this problem would be appreciated . I have no idea whether its the code's fault or the simulator.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var mySwitch: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet var Answer: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var tempInput: UITextField!

    //aqnswer value

    @IBAction func switchPressed(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        if ( mySwitch.on ) {
            self.Answer.text = "cel to fah"
        }
        else
        {
            self.Answer.text = "fah to cel"
        }
    }
        //textfield value

    @IBAction func calculate(sender: AnyObject)
            {
                //get user input 
                // value = celcius

                var Value:Int = tempInput.text.toInt()!
                var toFah :Int = ( 32 + Value * 9 ) / 5

                //to celcius

                var toCel: Int = (Value-32) * 5 / 9

                if (mySwitch.on)
                {
                    self.Answer.text = toFah.description
                }
                else {
                    self.Answer.text = toCel.description
                }

               // println(fah)
               // Answer.text = fah.description
                }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting ? Is there any error log in console ?

Comment: i am getting   " terminating with an uncaught exception of type NES excption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there could be a number of things that are wrong here.

1) If you are using storyboard to design the UI. Check if Viewcontroller has been set as the initial viewcontroller. You should see an arrow thats pointing at the first view controller.

2) Put in some print messages in viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear functions. This should tell you if the view controller is getting loaded.

3) Another common mistake : And this probably is what is happening. I see you have a button, right click on the button in the storyboard and see what all methods/outlets it is connected to. Some times, when you make a connection from storyboard to code. Using Control + Drag. And if you later delete the code. Storyboard still retains the link to the code.
At launch it tries to connect to the code and if it doesnt find the outlet or IBaction it causes a crash.

Comment: its connected to the calculate method that i have. should i delete the button and the method and redo it again?

Comment: If you right click on the button and see that the button is only connected to the calculate function its fine. 

Also check the other UIelements you have in the view. 

If you could post the entire error log, I could tell you where the error is.

Comment: 015-11-17 10:16:13.379 tempConverter[4950:48277] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<tempConverter.ViewController 0x7fe97a527d60> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key switch.'

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb) @TheAppMentor

Comment: Yes, thats the problem, Check the UI element called "key switch", it must be connected to some code, that you either deleted or modified.

Right click on the UI element called "key switch", you should see where its linked to the code. I see you have an IBaction called @IBAction func switchPressed(sender: AnyObject)

Comment: i did modified the name of the id for the switch that i have . u think thats the problem?

Comment: Yes. Just delete the "key switch" from the storyboard, add it again and connect it to the function. That should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95368/discussion-between-theappmentor-and-shiva-upadhyay).

Answer (score 0):

Terrible controller naming aside, it seems like your storyboard has no entry scene (and your controller is probably not referenced there, if you create one). Xcode should give you a warning on the first problem, though.

That white screen is the default launch screen; it will go away as soon as the root view controller gets installed by the storyboard (asuming you use that).

Comment: do u have a link on how to do it? or can you show me how to do that , like edit my question or something.  I am new and completely lost at this. pleaseee. thank you

Comment: In interface builder, check the root scene of the storyboard. refer to the apple documentation, here seems like a good starting point: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/Storyboard.html

Answer (score 0):

1. In Interface Builder, are you sure that ViewController is the class associated with the starting controller ?
2. Can we have a screenshot of the ViewController in Interface Builder? (because from the problem explanation i understand you set up a view in Interface Builder with a text field, a button and a switch button
3. I believe 99% of the time this is the code's fault...